# Discord.py No react emojis on output

Tags: python, discord.py

When I type /helps I receive only "Hello, Raw" Are there any errors in my code, because I didn't get the react emojis.

Output :
Hello Raw#6839

```
from discord.ext import menus,commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=('/'))

class MyMenu(menus.Menu):
    async def send_initial_message(self, ctx, channel):
        return await channel.send(f'Hello {ctx.author}')

    @menus.button('\n{TRACK PREVIOUS SIGN}')
    async def on_track_previous(self, ctx, payload):
        await self.message.edit(content="a")

    @menus.button('\n{REWIND SIGN}')
    async def on_rewind(self, ctx, payload):
        await self.message.edit(content="b")

    @menus.button('\n{FAST FORWARD SIGN}')
    async def on_fast_forward(self, ctx, payload):
        await self.message.edit(content="c")

    @menus.button('\n{TRACK NEXT SIGN}')
    async def on_track_next(self, ctx, payload):
        await self.message.edit(content="d")

@bot.command()
async def helps(ctx):
    m = MyMenu()
    await m.start(ctx)

bot.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using valid name escapes.  The syntax requires a capital N, and you need to use the precise names of those characters (you can use `"<char>".encode('ascii', 'namereplace')` to get these)

```
class MyMenu(menus.Menu):
    async def send_initial_message(self, ctx, channel):
        return await channel.send(f'Hello {ctx.author}')

    @menus.button('\N{BLACK LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE WITH VERTICAL BAR}\N{VARIATION SELECTOR-16}')
    async def on_track_previous(self, ctx, payload):
        await self.message.edit(content="a")

    @menus.button('\N{BLACK LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE}')
    async def on_rewind(self, ctx, payload):
        await self.message.edit(content="b")

    @menus.button('\N{BLACK RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE}')
    async def on_fast_forward(self, ctx, payload):
        await self.message.edit(content="c")

    @menus.button('\N{BLACK RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE WITH VERTICAL BAR}\N{VARIATION SELECTOR-16}')
    async def on_track_next(self, ctx, payload):
        await self.message.edit(content="d")
```